Upgraded from Craft 3 -> 5 Redactor Update Loop
Upgraded from Craft 3 > Craft 5. Updating all plugins as I go, though when I got to 5 and tried upgrading Redactor I keep hitting the same error:

"You need to be using at least Redactor 3.0.0 before you can update to
Redactor 4.2.0."

I've tried the following:

Clone Redactor/Htmlfields Folder from old site, nuking /vendor and .lock and composer install. <- Didn't work
Nuke /vendor and lock and install with redactor 4.2.0 in the composer.json. <- Didn't work.
Old version of Redactor it's after requires a downgrade to Craft 4 to install.

